# Add a column for rank, then ranking by group

Tags: r

I have managed to add a column for ranking for my data frame

```
lowest.mortality.upper<-nrow(lowest.mortality)
## Add a ranking column
lowest.mortality$ranking<-c(1:lowest.mortality.upper)
```

However now I have to rank a bigger dataset based on another column state. So it would read

```
AK 1
AK 2
TX 1
TX 2
TX 3
```

I could use a for loop but thats so 1980's. I'm sure that subset or lapply should work but I can't figure out how

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to add a sequence column by group.  There are several options.

A `base R`  solution using `ave` is

```
df1$indx <- with(df1, ave(seq_along(grp), grp, FUN=seq_along))
```

---

Or this can be done with `getanID` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
getanID(df1, 'grp')[]
#    grp .id
#1:  AK   1
#2:  AK   2
#3:  TX   1
#4:  TX   2
#5:  TX   3
```

---

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(grp) %>%
   mutate(indx = row_number())
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(grp = c("AK", "AK", "TX", "TX", "TX")), .Names = 
"grp", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I used the ave solution which worked perfectly. Now I just have to work out what it actually does....